# How to proof in this case $\sum_{n=-∞}^∞ f(n^2x)$ is equal almost anywhere in (-∞, +∞) to a Lebesgue integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis

f(x) is a Lebesgue integrable function in (-∞, +∞) ,and f(0)=0. How to proof $$\sum_{n=-∞}^∞ f(n^2x)$$ is equal almost anywhere in (-∞, +∞) to a Lebesgue integrable function ?

In my opinion, Levi Theorem is the key. However, I cannot proof that this case meets the condition of Levi Theorem after I tried to use a continuous function or a stage function converge to f(x). Is my way wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|f(n^2 x)|$, which is a non-negative series and therefore converges to a number in $[0,\infty]$. Regarding the sum as an integral and applying Tonelli's Theorem yields that
$$
\int h(x)\ dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\int|f(n^2 x)|\ dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}}\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \int |f(x)|\ dx=\frac{\pi^2}{3}\int |f(x)|\ dx<\infty,
$$
from which it follows that the set $N=\{x\in\mathbb R\colon h(x)=\infty\}$ is a null set. Thus the series converges absolutely for almost every $x$, and the function
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}f(n^2 x),\qquad x\in \mathbb R\setminus N
$$
is integrable due to the triangle inequality.